# CA2225, IConvertible, and release build performance

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, release, compiler-optimization, iconvertible

I'm creating an object that exposes explicit and implicit casting operators. Code Analysis suggested that I also create named methods to match ([CA2225: Operator overloads have named alternates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182355.aspx)). Also, I chose to implement `IConvertible`, which contains a bunch of ToXXX methods, although it takes an `IFormatProvider` as an argument.

Most of these are alternative ways to do the same code, so I'm wondering if when compiling in release mode, will it optimize/inline my calls to negate performance issues so I don't have to have repeating code.

For example:

```
public byte ToByte()
{
    // My code that I don't want to copy/paste.
}

public static explicit operator Byte(MyObject obj)
{
    return obj.ToByte();
}

byte IConvertible.ToByte(IFormatProvider provider)
{
    return ToByte(); //I don't care about the provider in this case.
}
```

Comment: It recommends that you worry about somebody using Cobol.NET having trouble using your class.  They certainly will.

Comment: @HansPassant: I understand why I have to follow CA2225, but I'm wondering if the release compiler will optimize my code if it recognizes that my operator simply calls the `ToXXX()` method, and the same with the `IConvertible` methods, they simply call the `ToXXX()` method.

Comment: The Cobol compiler?  I'm not old enough to know.  Well, care.  CA2225 is a typical "I bet you didn't know, it might matter" kind of message.  Always good to be reminded about things you didn't know might matter.  The odds that it does are very small.  But then again, you didn't actually describe anything about your environment so it actually *might* matter.  FxCop is a fountain-of-useless-knowledge kind of program that's right about 5% of the time.  Those 5% can really matter.  You need to use the tool between your ears to know if it does.

Comment: @HansPassant: No, I'm wondering about the standard compilers for .NET.